# VBScript + ASP Clasico - Error al escribir un archivo binario en el servidor

Tags: asp, vbscript, upload

Estoy trabajando un código de una aplicación en ASP Clásico antigua, que no se puede migrar a .Net por el momento, y una de las funciones que se usa para subir archivos de Excel a una carpeta del servidor para procesamientos posterior repentinamente ha comenzado a fallar esta semana, después de más de nueve años funcionando sin errores.
El bloque que genera el fallo es el siguiente:

```
        VarPathCompleta = ToFolder & "\" & filename
        Dim MyFileObject
        Set MyFileObject = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim objFile,value,i
        Set objFile = MyFileObject.CreateTextFile(VarPathCompleta, true)
        value = UploadRequest.Item(ParamObjFile).Item("Value")
        For i = 1 to LenB(value)
            objFile.Write chr(AscB(MidB(value,i,1)))
        Next          

        objFile.Close
        Set objFile = Nothing
        Set MyFileObject = Nothing
```

Lo que hace es bastante estándar: Recorre un archivo que ha sido obtenido en UploadRequest, y lo recorre byte a byte para escribirlo en otro que se creó en el servidor. 
El código es similar a otros que he encontrado en la web, y hasta ahora funcionaba bien.
El error se está produciendo al ejecutar el .Write, **pero solamente luego de procesar los primeros 16 bytes**, y en ese punto dispara el error "*Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución error '800a0005' Argumento o llamada a procedimiento no válidos*", sin mas detalles.
He debuggeado el proceso y sólo pude determinar que es al momento de **escribir** ese 17vo byte, ya que las funciones Chr(), AscB() y MidB() funcionan correctamente.
También he verificado los archivos de Excel a procesar, y se encuentran en perfecto estado.
Busqué documentación de este caso en la Web durante cinco días, sin encontrar nada semejante, salvo una mención de errores en upload con ASP Clásico luego de un fix de Microsoft de hace un pare de años, por lo que no creo que se trate exactamente de eso. Aun espero confirmación de loa administradores del webserver.

En resumen: ¿Qué puede estar causando que este método .Write haya comenzado a fallar en esta circunstancia? ¿Hay algún error conocido semejante?

Como nota, estamos evaluando el uso de ADODB.Stream para resolverlo, pero la directiva que tengo es procurar no modificar el código porque tiene muchos impactos cruzados en otras funcionalidades.

Comment: verifica que el servidor tenga una versión de [MDAC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/301202/how-to-check-for-mdac-version) compatible con la versión de asp y vbscript

Comment: Bienvenido @G'Kuan a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El servidor es empresarial y está completamente configurado con todo lo necesario (no es la unica aplicación propia que corre), como ya comenté, se trata de una aplicación que ha estado productiva desde hace al menos diez años, y el error se ha presentado desde el jueves pasado. La aplicación se usa 24/7 y la clase que usa el método se ha estado usando diariamente sin problemas (no ha tenido cambios desde 2009). ESO es precisamente por lo que no podemos entender el fallo.

Comment: Con un debuggeo cuidadoso estoy viendo que por alguna razón el código obtiene un byte cuyo valor ANSI es ilegal.
Por un lado obtiene un AscB = 208, que Char() no puede interpretar, y por otro el 103, en oro momento. Ambos son ilegales, pero no me explica por qué estaba funcionando hasta hace una semana.

Answer (score 1):

Bien. Finalmente pudimos resolver el incidente, aunque no pudimos saber ni por qué el código original funcionó bien durante años para fallar hace poco, ni como es siquiera posible que haya funcionado alguna vez...
Explico: El código original tenía por objeto resolver un tema de seguridad en aplicaciones Web donde en la extranet no se puede subir directamente (upload) un archivo a una carpeta interna de la web. La seguridad que normalmente se usa para estos temas lo impide, y es razonable que lo haga.
El método usado es abrir el documento en memoria y luego volverlo a escribir en la carpeta. De ese modo no se @copia@, sino que se almacena el contenido.
Ahora, el tema es que subir un archivo de texto es fácil con Scripting.FileSystemObject, porque está preparado para procesar archivos de texto, pero NO para trabajar con archivos binarios. Y ese es el drama de nuestro caso.
Simplemente, el código usado JAMÁS debió funcionar. NUNCA. 
Pero lo hizo por alguna extraña razón.
En definitiva, la solución fue cambiar el Scripting.FileSystemObject por un objeto ADODB.Stream. Pero para que realmente funcionase, lo que se lee en el Stream debe ser escrito como binario de nuevo. Y para eso se requiere una función que convierta lo leído en un objeto que se pueda escribir, para esto último se usa una función (que obtuve en una web - [ver aqui](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2084600-vbscript-can-someone-tell-me-what-this-vbscript-does)).

Parte 1:

```
    If UploadRequest.Item(ParamObjFile).Item("Value") <> "" Then
    contentType = UploadRequest.Item(ParamObjFile).Item("ContentType")
    filepathname = UploadRequest.Item(ParamObjFile).Item("FileName")
    filename = Right(filepathname,Len(filepathname)-InstrRev(filepathname,"\"))

    ToFolder = GetPath() & ParamCarpetaUp

    Dim VarPathCompleta

    filename = Replace(ParamNombre," ","")          

    VarPathCompleta = ToFolder & "\" & filename
    Const adTypeBinary = 1
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Dim objStream, fileObj
    Dim value

    value = MultiByteToBinary(UploadRequest.Item(ParamObjFile).Item("Value"))

    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Open
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary

    objStream.Write value

    objStream.SaveToFile VarPathCompleta, adSaveCreateOverWrite

    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
 End If
```

Parte 2 (funcion)

```
  private Function MultiByteToBinary(MultiByte)
    ' Esta función convierte una cadena multibyte en un dato binario real data (VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY)
    ' Usando recordset
    Dim RS, LMultiByte
    Const adLongVarBinary = 205
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    LMultiByte = LenB(MultiByte)
    RS.Fields.Append "mBinary", adLongVarBinary, LMultiByte
    RS.Open
    RS.AddNew
    RS("mBinary").AppendChunk MultiByte & ChrB(0)
    RS.Update
    MultiByteToBinary = RS("mBinary").GetChunk(LMultiByte)
    RS.Close
    set RS = nothing
End Function
```

Espero que nadie tenga necesidad de este incordio... pero sino, aquí está.